# How do I remove a substring with repeating pattern in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

So, I have the following list:

```
texts = ["Vol. 1, No. 2, 2020 other text yes bla bla",
        "Vol. 2, No. 2, 2020 another text",
        "Vol. 1, No. 1, 2020 yet another one"]
```

See, I want to get that another text, other text, etc, and remove the "Vol. x No. x, 2020" substring. How do I do it using regex? I thought that using `{}` would help me remove it, but it seems like I don't really understand how it works.

```
def remove_header_footer(text):
    pattern1 = "Vol. {}, No. {}, 2020"
    temp = text.replace(pattern1, text, "")
```

And I got an error. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected output list here?

Comment: 1) `str.replace`  does not support regex based replacement, `re.sub` is used for that, 2) `{}` does not match digits, `\d+` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this pattern `'Vol. \d, No. \d, 2020'` given that the string after Vol. and No. is a single digit. For multiple digits, you can use \d+

```
import re
texts = ["Vol. 1, No. 2, 2020 other text yes bla bla",
         "Vol. 2, No. 2, 2020 another text",
         "Vol. 1, No. 1, 2020 yet another one"]
for text in texts:
    new_text = re.sub('Vol. \d, No. \d, 2020', '', texts[0])
    print(new_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the alignment is always the same, you could try this easy approach:

```
result = []
for text in texts:
    text_split = text.split(" ")
    result.append(text_split[5:])
```

this would seperate at every ";" in your list and then split at every `blank`. Later the first 5 entries are omitted when appending to the result list. You could then flatten the list if you wish:

```
flat_result = [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

If texts are always formatted this way you might `.split` them at `2020` once and bring last part i.e.

```
texts = ["Vol. 1, No. 2, 2020 other text yes bla bla",
        "Vol. 2, No. 2, 2020 another text",
        "Vol. 1, No. 1, 2020 yet another one"]
for t in texts:
    print(t.split(" 2020 ", 1)[-1])
```

output

```
other text yes bla bla
another text
yet another one
```

Note that I split at space 2020 space rather than 2020 and do it once (2nd argument in `.split` is 1) so there is no problem if 2020 appear in further test.